# PHPSESSID Cookie automatically created without calling session_start()

Tags: php, session, cookies

Why is PHPSESSID Cookie automatically created even if i didn't call session_start() function, even if i didn't wrote a single line of php code, but when i check dev-tools in my browser cookie is there and it has 32bit string value. I succeeded to get it's value on the very first line of php code.
When i delete it and refresh my page new cookie with new value is automatically generated.

Why is this happening? Does maybe php or XAMPP do it under the hood or this is normal behaviour and i didn't get this concept properly

Comment: You can configure PHP to start sessions automatically, but you can't possibly get a brand new PHPSESSID cookie if you aren't running PHP at all. When you talk about refreshing your page, what's your browser loading exactly? A static asset? A not found error page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is INI-Setting (session.auto_start = 1) that most probably causes this issue.

Please check your .ini-Settings.